Rebooting breaks dns-server docker container
This is my ~/docker-webdev-stack/docker-compose.yml
services:
  dns-server:
    container_name: dns-server
    hostname: dns-server
    image: technitium/dns-server:latest
    # For DHCP deployments, use "host" network mode and remove all the port mappings, including the ports array by commenting them
    # network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "5380:5380/tcp" #DNS web console (HTTP)
      - "53443:53443/tcp" #DNS web console (HTTPS)
      - "53:53/udp" #DNS service
      - "53:53/tcp" #DNS service
    environment:
      - DNS_SERVER_DOMAIN=dns-server #The primary domain name used by this DNS Server to identify itself.
      - DNS_SERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password #DNS web console admin user password.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_HTTP_PORT=5380 #The TCP port number for the DNS web console over HTTP protocol.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_HTTPS_PORT=53443 #The TCP port number for the DNS web console over HTTPS protocol.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_ENABLE_HTTPS=true #Enables HTTPS for the DNS web console.
      - DNS_SERVER_WEB_SERVICE_USE_SELF_SIGNED_CERT=false #Enables self signed TLS certificate for the DNS web console.
      - DNS_SERVER_ENABLE_BLOCKING=false #Sets the DNS server to block domain names using Blocked Zone and Block List Zone.
      - DNS_SERVER_FORWARDERS=1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8 #Comma separated list of forwarder addresses.
      - DNS_SERVER_LOG_USING_LOCAL_TIME=true #Enable this option to use local time instead of UTC for logging.
    volumes:
      - config:/etc/dns
    networks:
      dns-network:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.2
    restart: always
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65000

  gitea-server:
    image: gitea/gitea:1.17.3
    container_name: gitea
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - GITEA__database__DB_TYPE=mysql
      - GITEA__database__HOST=gitea-db:3306
      - GITEA__database__NAME=gitea
      - GITEA__database__USER=gitea
      - GITEA__database__PASSWD=gitea
    restart: always
    networks:
      - dns-network
    dns: 10.0.0.2
    volumes:
      - ./gitea:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/ssl/myCA.crt:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCA.crt:ro
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "222:22"
    depends_on:
      - gitea-db
      - dns-server

  gitea-db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: gitea-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - dns-server
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=gitea
      - MYSQL_USER=gitea
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=gitea
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=gitea
    networks:
      - dns-network
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    depends_on:
      - dns-server
    user: root
    ports:
      - "35000:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /etc/ssl/myCA.pem:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCA.crt:ro
      - /home/david/docker-webdev-stack/jenkins/run.sh:/var/jenkins_home/run.sh:ro
      - /home/david/docker-webdev-stack/jenkins/ssh-keys:/var/jenkins_home/.ssh
    networks:
      - dns-network
    dns: 10.0.0.2

volumes:
    config:
    jenkins_home:

networks:
  dns-network:
    name: dns-network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/16

When I restart the server, for whatever reason, even though I have restart: always I get this:
david<webdev>~
 11:30:14 λ sudo docker logs 590b12b8942d
Technitium DNS Server was started successfully.
Using config folder: /etc/dns

Note: Open http://dns-server:5380/ in web browser to access web console.

Press [CTRL + C] to stop...

Technitium DNS Server is stopping...
Technitium DNS Server was stopped successfully.

david<webdev>~
 11:30:16 λ sudo docker start 590b12b8942d
Error response from daemon: Address already in use
Error: failed to start containers: 590b12b8942d

david<webdev>~
 11:30:19 λ sudo netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21452           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35853         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53888           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:222             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::35000                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6379                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::53888                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::222                  :::*                    LISTEN

The container starts, then stops, and if I try to start it again I get Error response from daemon: Address already in use.
I can start it if I go to ~/docker-webdev-stack/ and do docker compose down and docker compose up -d
Any idea why rebooting breaks this? Could I make it so if dns-stops every other container also stops? And then they all restart? (Which I expected to happen with depends_on)
